# Firebase error (probably due to missing index) does not get caught

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I accidently deleted some of my Firebase indexes in the console. Now for one of the getting-data functions I get an Uncaught Firebase error. I assume this has to do with the missing indexes.

Usually I catch the error and then just click on the link in the console error to create the index. But in this case, the error does not get caught.

What's even more strange is that the function pointed out below in getData.js DOES retrieve the data. But I do not get data from another (Projects) collection anymore.

[image]

```
   //query to get the latest 30 profiles
      const qChangedByThisUser = query
        (
          collectionGroup(db, 'profiles'),
          where('latestupdatebyuser', '==', user.uid),
          orderBy("latestupdatetimestamp", "desc"),
          limit(30)
        )

      //create realtime listener based on query
      unsubToProfilesRecentlyUpdatedByUser = onSnapshot(qChangedByThisUser, (querySnapshot) => {


        //get profiles

      },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error)
        }
      )
```

I also tried to recreate the index in the console manually, both with collection and collectiongroup, but it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: which firebase version you are using?

Comment: Apparently a different onSnapshot (also with a missing index) was the problem. Which is weird is that the console error indicated the previous function described above... Anyway I was able to fix it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

So apparently a different onSnapshot (also with a missing index) was the problem. Which is weird because that the console error indicated the previous function described above... Anyway I was able to fix it by logging the error on this other snapshot and create the index